# What is the use of Index attribute in jqgrid colModel?

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I'm newbie to jqGrid, Can anybody explain what is the use of Index attribute in jqgrid colModel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use `datatype: "json"` or `datatype: "xml"` **without** additional usage of `loadonce: true` parameters then the sorting and filtering of data have to be implemented on the *server* side. For example if you have the column defined as

```js
{ name: "colName1", index: "colIndex1", ...}
```

then if the user clicks on the column header jqGrid will send Ajax request to the server with the parameters `sidx=colIndex1`. So one can use `index` option to hold the name of the field in the database to simplify building of `ORDER BY` part of the corresponding `SELECT` statement.

In the most cases one need to use `index` property which is the same as `name` property. In case of usage `datatype: "local"` or in case of the usage `datatype: "json"` or `datatype: "xml"` *togather* with `loadonce: true` the data will be saved *locally* in the grid in `data` and `_index` internal options. In the case one need to use `index` values which are the values from `name` properties of `colModel`. In the cases **it's strictly recommended don't specify any `index` property in `colModel`**. In the case jqGrid will use `name` property instead.